# prevent user from copying the text using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, html

how do i prevent the user from Copying any text in asp.net page using jQuery?

Comment: Man, this is just as bad as "no right-clicky". Please, save everyone the trouble and just don't. All you're doing is punishing your users.

Comment: No matter if the page was parsed by asp.net or other server-side languages, they are always html (if they are normal web pages).

Comment: ha ha ha ha

i really hate that too ,but my customer want it that way !!!

Comment: i know majid ,but is there any jQuery solution for this one?

Comment: I forsee this question will be closed. Sorry, can't resist. :) Okay, okay, I'm just kidding. :)

Comment: Grayson Peddie , take it easy. ;)

Comment: @HAJJAJ: "but my customer want it that way": time to start educating your customer (eg. demo getting the content of the page via `wget.exe` where no browser is involved, then show what Firebug etc. can do).

Comment: @HAJJAJ, I'd suggest you explain to your customer that's not feasible: even if you manage to lock the browser somehow (e.g. with an extension), I can still take a screenshot of your text, run it through an OCR engine and be on my merry way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable the right click and also bind keyup event on document to detect copy command key combination "Ctl + C" and returning false.

To disable right click:

```
jQuery(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

To detect Ctl + C:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    var ctlPressed = false; //Flag to check if pressed the CTL key
    var ctl = 17; //Key code for Ctl Key
    var c = 67; //Key code for "c" key

    jQuery(document).keydown(function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == ctl) 
          ctlPressed = true;
    }).keyup(function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == ctl) 
          ctlPressed = false;
    });

    jQuery(".your-no-copy-area").keydown(function(e)
    {
        if (ctlPressed && e.keyCode == c) 
          return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Watermark is your solution. I can easily disable Javascript.

Comment: And if it's text, then, uh well... You're screwed.

Comment: Watermark is good way but it will not work with Arabic character!!

Comment: Yeah, and turn your text into an image and you'll make your blind users not visit your website anymore (with screen readers, since screen readers don't have the way to interpret the image, let alone if it's a paragraph or not).

Comment: ha ha ha 

and it's not text box , it is a full paragraph!!

Comment: Well, then turn your full paragraph into an image if you don't care about blind users and those who use text-only web browsers. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is usually frowned upon, but if you have to do in, [here is a plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.text_selection.src.js.txt)

Answer (score 1):

well i used lots of codes to make this like :

1-to disable the right click:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(this).bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Copy is not allowed");
        });
    });       
</script>
```

2-disable Selection

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    /***********************************************
    * Disable Text Selection script- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
    * This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
    * Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
    ***********************************************/

    function disableSelection(target) {
        if (typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined") //IE route
            target.onselectstart = function () { return false }
        else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") //Firefox route
            target.style.MozUserSelect = "none"
        else //All other route (ie: Opera)
            target.onmousedown = function () { return false }
        target.style.cursor = "default"
    }

    //Sample usages
    //disableSelection(document.body) //Disable text selection on entire body
    //disableSelection(document.getElementById("mydiv")) //Disable text selection on element with id="mydiv"
```

var alltables = document.getElementsByTagName("table")
    for (var i = 0; i < alltables.length; i++)
        disableSelection(alltables[i]) //disable text selection within all tables on the page

3-I added those to the end of the body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var somediv = document.getElementById("page-wrap")
     disableSelection(somediv) //disable text selection within DIV with id="page-wrap"
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    disableSelection(document.body) //disable text selection on entire body of page
</script>
```

now all done .....

thanks guys ,that was really very helpful.